# How do you reset a Buffalo WZR-D1800H (with dd-wrt installed)?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt, buffalo-router

I [installed dd-wrt on my Buffalo WZR-D1800H](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Buffalo_WZR-D1800H) wifi router some time ago.

I've reset this device in the past, but it always takes me about 30 or more minutes to figure it out. Each time I finally reset it, I can't figure out what I did differently than all of the other failed attempts. This time, I just can't get it to reset.

Generally, here's what I do:

1. Hold down reset button while power is on for 60 seconds
2. Power off, still holding down reset for 60 more seconds
3. Power on, still holding down reset for 60 more seconds

I've also tried the same steps at [30 seconds per step](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gczCzP9Rry0).

Does anyone know an exact procedure that works every time you do it? Please tell me so I can make a note of it and not go through this each (infrequent) time I'm forced to do this.

Comment: Didn't know migrated questions brought the view as well.

Answer (score 0):

once DD-WRT is installed the "ROUTER" button on the top of the back of the unit becomes the reset button!

Press and hold for 10 seconds.